# python, elegant way of creating vectors

Tags: python

what is elegant way to create set of ALL vectors of dimension N, that each element is integer between 0 and K inclusive ([0, K]).

my current code is :

```
def nodes_init(n, k):
    nodes = {}
    e = np.identity(n)
    nodes[tuple(np.zeros(n))] = 0
    s = Set()
    s.add(tuple(np.zeros(n)))
    s_used = Set()
    while len(s) != 0:
        node = s.pop()
        if node in s_used:
            continue
        s_used.add(node)
        for i in xrange(len(e)):
            temp = node + e[i]
            temp = cap(temp, k)
            temp = tuple(temp)
            nodes[temp] = 0
            if not temp in s_used:
                s.add(temp)
    return nodes

def cap(t, k):
    for i in xrange(len(t)):
        if t[i] > k:
            t[i] = k
    return t
```

and I don't like it.
keys of dictionary `nodes` are desired vectors.

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you want this? Won't you end up with K^N vectors? (a lot)

Comment: I am playing with trees, in my case n and k not so bit, computer can handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import product

def nodes_iter(n, k):
    """ returns generator (lazy iterator) rather than creating whole list """
    return product(range(k+1),repeat=n)
```

Example usage:

```
for node in nodes_iter(3,1):
    print node


(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: `product` takes a keyword argument `repeat`. So, `product(range(k+1), repeat=n)` will do. And note that `k` is inclusive. So `range(k+1)` instead of `range(k)`.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the answer as per Avaris's comment (and after testing on the console).

Comment: @Roberto: thanks for the edit, but I was editing at the same time